# Running a specific gradle task depending on android built type

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to running a specific task/action depending on build type -- either debug or release.

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        println "buildType.name is $buildType.name"
    }
}
```

But no matter if I run assembleDebug or assembleRelease my code gets executed for both build types:

```
10:56:20 PM: Executing external task 'assembleDebug'...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
buildType.name is debug
buildType.name is release
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:curl:compileLint
:curl:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:curl:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:curl:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:curl:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:curl:checkReleaseManifest
:curl:prepareReleaseDependencies
:curl:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:curl:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:curl:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:curl:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:curl:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:curl:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:curl:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:curl:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:curl:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPercent2301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAppboyAndroidSdkUi182Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComBraintreepaymentsApiBraintree164Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComBraintreepaymentsCardForm201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers131Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta113Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics251Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore234Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComEdmodoCropper101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonTimberTimber410Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComRaizlabsAndroidDBFlow221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoBranchSdkAndroidLibrary1811Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric135Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareParaboCurlUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
:app:jrebelPinDebugResids
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:curl:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:curl:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:curl:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:curl:checkDebugManifest
:curl:prepareDebugDependencies
:curl:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:curl:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:curl:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:curl:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:curl:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:curl:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:curl:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:curl:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:curl:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:curl:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:curl:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugJrebelLayout
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
:app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:jrebelPostProcessDebugResids
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
:app:assembleDebug
:curl:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:curl:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 10.657 secs
10:56:31 PM: External task execution finished 'assembleDebug'.
```

Why is that happening?

What's the proper way to detect a current build type?

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the build depend on the task for different builds

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        build.dependsOn 'mySweetReleaseTask'
    }
    debug {
        build.dependsOn 'mySweetDebugTask'
    }
}
```

Or

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        project.getTasks().getByName('build').dependsOn('mySweetReleaseTask')
    }
    debug {
        project.getTasks().getByName('build').dependsOn('mySweetDebugTask')
    }
}
```

If you want your task to run at a specific time for instance during the tests then you could replace the `'build'` with `'check'`.  This configuration block is evaluated during the configuration phase before the build actually begins (execution phase).

Comment: This didn't work for me with AGP 7.2.2

Comment: What did work was `preBuild.dependsOn '...'` instead